# Does Warden manage sessions?

Tags: ruby, warden

I've created a login app in Sinatra and authenticated with Warden. I can login, logout, manage protected page using Warden, but can't access my session information afterwards. Why is that? Is Warden not managing my session data? Please help me guys, I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. We can use the method env['warden].user to access user info.